# How to open safari, mail and doing call by html href link in UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview

I need to do three task in UIWebView,

1. Open safari,
2. Open mail
3. Place the call.

I know that i can do it by using UIApplication's openURL, but i need to do by using UIWebView only, because my data is coming from server, and i need to do this task in that data, if data has www.link, email addres or call number.

Does anyone knows that what is the actual idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="tel:34444444">a</a>
<a href="sms:34234234">b</a>
<a href="mailto:abc@gmail.com">c</a>
```